# Faster copyfiles Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, copy, vectorization, cell-array

I have a folder `origin_training` with subfolders like `FM`, `folder1`, `folder2`, `...` . I can get the list of image files in `.png` format into a cell called `FM`.

```
FM_dir = fullfile(origin_training, 'FM');
FM = struct2cell(dir(fullfile(FM_dir, '*.png')))';
```

My goal is to match the names in my folder with the images in my `cd`, and make a new folder `FM` with the images from `cd`. Image names in the two paths are identical. I can do that with:

```
% mother_folder = '...' my current directory
filenames = FM(:,1);
destination = fullfile(mother_folder, 'FM', FM(:,1));
cellfun(@copyfile,filenames, destination);
```

**This is really slow. Takes minutes even for small amounts of images (~30).**

My current directory has ~ 10000 images (the ones that correspond to `FM`, `folder2`, `folder3`, ...). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to create a shell command and execute it. Assuming `FM` contains full paths for each file, or relative paths from the current directory, then:

```
FM_dir = fullfile(origin_training, 'FM');
destination = fullfile(mother_folder, 'FM');
curdir = cd(FM_dir);
FM = dir('*.png');
cmd = ['cp ', sprintf('%s ',FM.name), destination];
system(cmd);
cd(curdir);
```

If you're on Windows, replace `'cp'` by `'copy'`.

Note that here we're not creating a shell command per file to be copied (presumably what `copyfile` does), but a single shell command that copies all files at once. We're also not specifying the name for each copied file, we specify the names of the files to be copied and where to copy them to.

Note also that for this to work, `mother_folder` must be an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow put my code into a function and now it works at expected speed. I suspected that `cd` had to do with the low speed so I am only passing the full directories as character vectors.
The same approach works for my purpose or with a slight modification to just copy from `A` to `B`. As now, it works to match files in `A` to those on `B` and copy to `B/folder_name`

```
function [out] = my_copyfiles(origin_dir, folder_name, dest_dir, extension)

new_dir = fullfile(origin_dir, folder_name);

% Get a cell with filenames in the origin_dir/folder_name
% Mind transposing to have them in the rows
NEW = struct2cell(dir(fullfile(new_dir, extension)))';

dest_folder = fullfile(dest_dir, folder_name);

% disp(dest_folder)

if ~exist(dest_folder, 'dir')
mkdir(dest_folder)
end

%% CAUTION, This is the step
% Use names from NEW to generate fullnames in dest_dir that would match
filenames = fullfile(dest_dir, NEW(:,1));
destination = fullfile(dest_folder, NEW(:,1));

% if you wanted from origin, instead run
% filenames = fullfile(new_dir, NEW(:,1));

% make the copies
cellfun(@copyfile,filenames, destination);

%Save the call

out.originDir = new_dir;
out.copyFrom = dest_dir;
out.to = dest_folder;
out.filenames = filenames;
out.destination = destination;

end
```